# PHP random string generator with custom choice

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a "special" string generator, with a custom selection for which characters you want.
shortly in the code when you call this function:

```
generateRandomString(length, [special characters], [numbers], [lower characters], [upper characters]);
```

for example:

```php
generateRandomString(5, true, true, true, true);
```

the code should be max 5 characters, with letters, numbers and special characters... like: fE3%!

but is gives me 5 random string for each bool active so if it 4 I have back 20 characters instead of 5

this is the code, what am I doing wrong?

```
function generateRandomString($length, $special, $numbers, $upper, $lower)
{
    //$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $characters["special"] = "!%";
    $characters["numbers"] = "01";
    $characters["upper"] = "ABC";
    $characters["lower"] = "abc";
    $randomString = '';
 
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
        if($special)
        {
            $randomString .= $characters["special"][rand(0, strlen($characters["special"]) - 1)];
        }
        if($numbers)
        {
            $randomString .= $characters["numbers"][rand(0, strlen($characters["numbers"]) - 1)];
        }
        if($upper)
        {
            $randomString .= $characters["upper"][rand(0, strlen($characters["upper"]) - 1)];
        }
        if($lower)
        {
            $randomString .= $characters["lower"][rand(0, strlen($characters["lower"]) - 1)];
        }
    }
 
    return $randomString;
}
```

Comment: You called the function with `true` as value for all those parameter that you are then checking in your if conditions there - so _all_ of these conditions are true, and since you don't change the parameter values in between either, they are true in _all_ loop iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first build valid characters range based on given parameters, and only then build random string.

Added validator to ensure that at least one character from each required group exists in random string.

```
function generateRandomString($length, $special, $numbers, $upper, $lower)
{
    //$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $characters["special"] = "!%";
    $characters["numbers"] = implode('', range(0, 9));
    $characters["upper"] = implode('', range('A', 'Z'));
    $characters["lower"] = implode('', range('a', 'z'));

    $charactersSet = '';
    $validators = [];
    $randomString = '';

    if ($special) {
        $charactersSet .= $characters["special"];
        $validators[] = '/[' . preg_quote($characters["special"]) . ']/';
    }

    if ($numbers) {
        $charactersSet .= $characters["numbers"];
        $validators[] = '/\d/';
    }
    
    if ($upper) {
        $charactersSet .= $characters["upper"];
        $validators[] = '/[A-Z]/';
    }

    if ($lower) {
        $charactersSet .= $characters["lower"];
        $validators[] = '/[a-z]/';
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $charactersSet[rand(0, strlen($charactersSet) - 1)];
    }

    foreach ($validators as $pattern) {
        if (preg_match($pattern, $randomString) === 0) {
            $randomString = generateRandomString($length, $special, $numbers, $upper, $lower);

            break;
        }
    }

    return $randomString;
}
```

Comment: It seems this work, thank you, I don't understand well this code, but now I'm studying it so next time I'll be prepared

Comment: @OuDayas Basically you first set up what possible values can be in your string. Then try to make random string from it. Finally check if all required elements (uppercase, lowercase, specials, etc.) exists in your string. If not - repeat process calling same function with same parameters until you get what you want

Comment: Is possible to make that doesn't give the same value when the function work? because i noticed that for example: i made a button with a simple js alert, everytime i press it, the code give me back the same string until i reload the page

Comment: @OuDayas That is not possible if calling this function properly. Maybe you cache it somewhere in variable?

Answer (score 0):

try to change the for loop to while loop like this :

```
function generateRandomString($length, $special, $numbers, $upper, $lower)
    {
        //$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $characters["special"] = "!%";
        $characters["numbers"] = "01";
        $characters["upper"] = "ABC";
        $characters["lower"] = "abc";
        $randomString = '';
     
        while(strlen($randomString) <= $length)
        {
            if($special)
            {
                $randomString .= $characters["special"][rand(0, strlen($characters["special"]) - 1)];
            }
            if($numbers && strlen($randomString) <= $length)
            {
                $randomString .= $characters["numbers"][rand(0, strlen($characters["numbers"]) - 1)];
            }
            if($upper && strlen($randomString) <= $length)
            {
                $randomString .= $characters["upper"][rand(0, strlen($characters["upper"]) - 1)];
            }
            if($lower  && strlen($randomString) <= $length)
            {
                $randomString .= $characters["lower"][rand(0, strlen($characters["lower"]) - 1)];
            }
        }
     
        return $randomString;
    }
```

Updated :
(for exemple the length equel to 5)
for while not breaked if we don't have 5 steps
while loop for every step check if the string length not 5
also checking for every nested condition if the string has equel to 5

Comment: It not work, this give me back a random string lenght every character in the setting,
I need the function give me a random string length how much I want for every character selected on the true,
I mean, if i write:
generateRandomString(5, true, true, false, false);
I need a string lenght 5 characters with only special characters and only number
or
generateRandomString(5, true, false, true, true);
I need a string of 5 characters with, special letters, upper and lower letters

Answer (score 0):

This solution picks a random range of characters on each iteration, then picks a random letter from that range of characters.

```
function generateRandomString($length, $special, $numbers, $upper, $lower)
{
    $alphabet = [
        '`~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{};\':",./<>?',
        '0123456789',
        'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
        'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    ];

    $allowable = [];
    if ($special)
        $allowable[] = 0;
    if ($numbers)
        $allowable[] = 1;
    if ($upper)
        $allowable[] = 2;
    if ($lower)
        $allowable[] = 3;

    $output = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        $which = $allowable[array_rand($allowable)];
        $alphabet_size = strlen($alphabet[$which])-1;
        $rand_character = rand(0, $alphabet_size);
        $output .= $alphabet[$which][$rand_character];
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: With your code it's possible to get just `JAHSKDJAK` even through you asked for special, numbers and uppercase